# Enforcing compatibility between numpy 1.8 and 1.9 nansum?

Tags: numpy

I have code that needs to behave identically independent of numpy version, but the underlying `np.nansum` function has changed behavior such that `np.nansum([np.nan,np.nan])` is `0.0` in 1.9 and `NaN` in 1.8.  The <=1.8 behavior is the one I would prefer, but the more important thing is that my code be robust against the numpy version.

The tricky thing is, the code applies an arbitrary numpy function (generally, a `np.nan[something]` function) to an ndarray. Is there any way to force the new or old numpy `nan[something]` functions to conform to the old or new behavior shy of monkeypatching them?

A possible solution I can think of is something like `outarr[np.allnan(inarr, axis=axis)] = np.nan`, but there is no `np.allnan` function - if this is the best solution, is the best implementation `np.all(np.isnan(arr), axis=axis)` (which would require only supporting np>=1.7, but that's probably OK)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Numpy 1.8, `nansum` was defined as:

```py
a, mask = _replace_nan(a, 0)

if mask is None:
    return np.sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
mask = np.all(mask, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)
tot = np.sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
if np.any(mask):
    tot = _copyto(tot, np.nan, mask)
    warnings.warn("In Numpy 1.9 the sum along empty slices will be zero.",
                  FutureWarning)
return tot
```

in Numpy 1.9, it is:

```py
a, mask = _replace_nan(a, 0)
return np.sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
```

I don't think there is a way to make the new `nansum` behave the old way, but given that the original `nansum` code isn't that long, can you just include a copy of that code (without the warning) if you care about preserving the pre-1.8 behavior?

Note that `_copyto` can be imported `numpy.lib.nanfunctions`

Comment: Good enough.  This won't solve the problem of a user passing `np.nansum` directly into one of our functions, but at least the existing code can be made to behave consistently by copying over all of the np 1.8 nanfunctions